# Deserialize json object that contains 3 sub-objects in c#

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services

I need to deserialize a JSON object.
The JSON contains 3 sub-objects.
The first two have properties, the last one has just single value.

How can i do that?

My JSON object looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "p": 
    [
      {
        "propP1": "LoremIpsum",
        "propP2": "100",
        "propP3": "1"
      }
    ],
    "c": 
     [
      {
        "propC1": "xxx1",
        "propC2": "xxx2",
        "propC3": "xxx3",
        "propC4": "xxx4"
      }
    ],
    "x": "1"
  }
]
```

Comment: @Der Golem - i didnt know how to cast values out of it without instantating dummy classes for 'p' and 'c'

Comment: You  wanted to answer to @PraveenPaulose 's comment

Comment: thank you :) ...yes my answer was for @PraveenPaulose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution ... I  can use type dynamic and then iterate my json

```
dynamic o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonObj);

            foreach (var item in o)
            {
                var x = item.p[0].propP1; // returns 'LoremIpsum'
                var y = item.[0].propC1; // returns 'xxx1'
            }
```